# Tagging and new environment

Tags: lists, environments, comments

I am using the `tagging` package in my document to "customize it. To include/exclude some parts of my document using a taglist, I could use the following : `\begin{taggedblock}{<taglist>}` and `\end{taggedblock}`. But I wanted to include this into a new environment (which is more complicated than the example which follows) so here is what I did :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tagging}

\newenvironment{myenvironment}[1]{\begin{taggedblock}{#1}}{\end{taggedblock}}

\usetag{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenvironment}{1,2}
test 1,2
\end{myenvironment}

\begin{myenvironment}{2}
test 2
\end{myenvironment}

\end{document}
```

But this example produces an error. From what I understand, the problem is this one : the way I defined `myenvironment`, it does not accept lists of tags. If I replace my second block with `\begin{myenvironment}{1,2} test 2 \end{myenvironment}` then there is no problem when I compile the document. How could I modify this environment to accept a list of tags ?

Answer (score 4):

If you define your environment as

```
\newenvironment{myenvironment}[1]{\taggedblock{#1}}{\endtaggedblock}
```

then things work:

[image]

### Note:

- I have seen this *trick* used when wrapping environment around `tabular` but not sure why it is needed.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tagging}

\newenvironment{myenvironment}[1]{\taggedblock{#1}}{\endtaggedblock}

\usetag{1}
%\droptag{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenvironment}{1,2}
test 1,2
\end{myenvironment}

\begin{myenvironment}{2}
test 2
\end{myenvironment}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I can see there is a small difference between your definition of `myenvironment` and mine. I assume the problem was coming from the use of `\begin` and `\end` inside the definition of the environment (I was more or less nesting environments), right ?

Comment: @jibounet: Yep. And usually the way you were nesting them is ok. But sometimes it is not (like with `tabular`).